# WCF: Select between regular and duplex service contract at runtime

Tags: wcf, generics, wcf-client

I am writing a WCF client/service.  The service can perform some long operations so I have added a callback contract `IProgressCallback`.  The system I am developing has to run in all kind of environments so I suspect that I will run into an environment where a callback channel cannot be opened (I might be wrong here).

So to be careful I have defined the operation contract like this.

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface IContract
{ ... }

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IProgress))]
interface IDuplexContract : IContract
{ ... }
```

This works great on the server side. I can easily configure the service to use either contract.

The problem however arises on the client side.  I have manually defined 2 proxies

```
public class ContractProxy 
   : ClientBase<IContract>, IContract
{ ... }

public class DuplexContractProxy 
   : DuplexClientBase<IDuplexContract>, IDuplexContract 
{ ... }
```

Again both proxies work fine.

Now I have a proxy factory which is responsible for creating the correct proxy.  It can easily figure out which proxy to instantiate but my problem arises when I try to return the proxy.

The user needs to get an object back that is at least `IContract` and  `ICommunicationObject` but I haven't been able to find what to return.  I have tried to the following:

```
IContract CreateProxy(...)  // The user lacks access to Open, Abort, Close, etc.
ClientBase<IContract> CreateProxy(...)  // DuplexClientBase derives from ClientBase but the generic parameter is different and it isn't covariant so this cannot be done.

// First define a generic interface and then make both proxies implement it.
IProxy<TContract> : TContract, ICommunicationObject  // TContract cannot be restricted to an interface so I cannot make IProxy derive from TContract
```

Currently as a workaround I am simply returning the IContract interface but then everyone using the proxy will have to start by casting it to a ICommunicationObject to open the proxy etc.

Does anyone here have a better way to do this or am I simply being overly worried that duplex communication might not work in some environments?